# Is it possible to find the coordinates of a letter in a text file by counting each character as 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app and I am trying to find the coordinates (not in pixels) of a letter in a string or text that is uploaded by the user. For example, the letter "A" will return for the text below:

A: { [(5,1), (6,2)] }  (means, 5th column & 1st row and 6th column & 2nd row has A, each dot or character counts as 1)

```
..00A000011.....000000

.0000A000B...........
```

Comment: And the rows are delimited by newlines? What have you tried so far? Note that "A: { (5,1), (6,2) }" is not any valid JS structure, so your output format is not all too clear, apart from that you want a list of tuples.

Comment: yes rows are delimited by newlines. it doesn't have to be exactly this format "A: { (5,1), (6,2) }" , but I need to get the numbers (5,1) and (6,2) for each A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
function search(str, char) {
  var lines = str.split('\n');

  var result = {
    [char]: []
  };

  for (let row = 0; row < lines.length; row++) {
    var letters = [...lines[row]];
    letters.forEach((letter, column) => {
      if (letter === char) {
        result[char].push([(column + 1), (row + 1)])
      }
    });
  }
  return result;
}

const str = `..00A000011.....000000
.0000A000B...........`;

console.log(search(str, 'A'));
```

Just one suggestion, it should be `(row, column)` not `(column, row)`. But if your requirement is `(column, row)` it's fine, the solution will just work.